# unit test mock imediator for cqrs

Tags: unit-testing, moq, mediator

I have a problem in an MVC, CQRS application. I'm trying to write a unit test for application layer, where the handler needs IMediator to be constructor injected, I'm trying to mock it with MOQ but there's clearly some setup missing:
[image]

The mediator is then used in the WorkOrder queryhandler to send a query to another object (Contact).

[image]

But I can't seem to get it to work, the second mediator call doesn't get to queryhandler.
Please is there someone that had the same problem or know how to set it up to work.

Comment: Code is text. Please share text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the way you set your initial mocks, I understand that you are passing in a mocked `Mediator` to your handler. Your call to `Send` via the handler fails because you are invoking through the mocked object. Ideally, you can mock the behaviour expected out of `Send` method and setup what you would want to return as a result of the `Send` call.

Bear in mind, you are using Mocks because you do not want the actual behaviour to be triggered within the context of the test.

Mocking the behaviour can be done as shown below

```
// within your test method
mediator.SetUp(m => m.Send(It.IsAny<GetContactDomainQuery>()))
        .Returns(<whatever you want your mocked behaviour to return>);
```

Take a look at the [documentation of Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for further understanding on various variations of Mocking.